# Read a grid from image Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, image-processing, maze

I need suggestions on reading a grid for maze generation purposes, i don't need code to generate a maze, all i need is a way to read an m x n grid from image and be able to iterate over cells and link/ unlink those cells. I already wrote some code that generates a grid using PIL, and i will be writing code to generate mazes using different algorithms.

Example:
[image]

Given a grid that will look like this and I need for example to modify cell 0, 0 and cell 0, 1 by linking them together by removing the wall | between them. Any suggestions on how to be able to modify the walls between cells in a method that might do something like the following:

```
def link_cells(cell1, cell2, grid):
    """Link 2 cells in a given image.
    cell1: a tuple (row, column)
    cell2: a tuple (row, column)
    grid: an image object (full grid)
    """
    # do ...
```

Note: I don't need an algorithm for maze generation, just something that enables the image processing part and i will work from there.

Comment: These images are being generated by you? If so, why do you not do these modifications before you write the maze to an image?

Comment: Because the code i wrote divides the image width/ height by the number of rows/ columns and draws a line in each section and it's not possible (or at least i don't know) how to generate a maze without initiating a grid with clear cells to work with like in the example above and i guess most of the maze generating algorithms rely on the same logic. I just need to be able to modify cell walls after the creation of the grid.

Comment: Why not start with a data structure to hold the information about the maze (a non-optimal first iteration could be a 3x3 2D array where each element contained information about the adjacent walls `[[Cell(), Cell(), Cell()], [Cell(), Cell(), Cell()], [Cell(), Cell(), Cell()]]`). Then work out how to draw this based on the data in each cell. Then you can modify this representation of your maze before drawing

Comment: I already did that using a class Cell, I need to translate it to image.

Comment: I don't understand. You say you want to **read** a grid in your question then you say you want to remove a wall between cells which is **writing** in my book. Does someone give you an image and you want to change it? Or did you draw the image, in which case your problem surely cannot be to know what you drew?

Comment: what I mean by read is the program being able to iterate over cells and if a call to link(cell1, cell2) the program erases the wall between them(what you refer to as writing)

Comment: If you are generating the image, you really should use PNG rather than JPEG. JPEG is **lossy** and it changes what you write into an image so it is different when you read it back. Do you have a PNG version of the image in your question please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a possible approach. Calculate the means of all the rows across the image into a single column wide vector as shown on the right in the diagram. Likewise calculate the means down all the columns into a single row high vector as shown across the bottom in the diagram:

[image]

Now threshold those two vectors, and then look for transition from white to black and from black to white. That will give you the start and end rows and columns of all the black lines in the image. You can now use those to overpaint in white the cell boundaries you want to erase. I overpainted in cyan and magenta so you can see what I am doing.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

# Open image and make greyscale and Numpy versions
pimRGB  = Image.open('grid.jpg')
pimgrey = pim.convert('L')
nimRGB  = np.array(pimRGB)
nimgrey = np.array(pimgrey)

# Work out where the horizontal lines are
rowmeans  = np.mean(nimgrey,axis=1)
rowthresh = np.where(rowmeans>128,255,0)
# Difference each element with its neighbour...
diffs = rowthresh[:-1] - rowthresh[1:]
rowStarts, rowEnds = [], []
for i,v in enumerate(diffs):
    if v>0:
        rowStarts.append(i)
    if v<0:
        rowEnds.append(i)

# Work out where the vertical lines are
colmeans  = np.mean(nimgrey,axis=0)
colthresh = np.where(colmeans>128,255,0)
# Difference each element with its neighbour...
diffs = colthresh[:-1] - colthresh[1:]
colStarts, colEnds = [], []
for i,v in enumerate(diffs):
    if v>0:
        colStarts.append(i)
    if v<0:
        colEnds.append(i)

# Now all our initialisation is finished

# Colour in cyan the 2nd black row starting after the 3rd black col
r, c = 2, 3
nimRGB[rowStarts[r]:rowEnds[r],colEnds[c]:colStarts[c+1]] = [0,255,255] 

# Colour in magenta the 8th black column starting after the 5th black row
r, c = 5, 8
nimRGB[rowEnds[r]:rowStarts[r+1],colStarts[c]:colEnds[c]] = [255,0,255] 

# Convert Numpy array back to PIL Image and save
Image.fromarray(nimRGB).save('result.png')
```

[image]

---

For reference, `colthresh` looks like this:

```
array([255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,   0,   0,   0,   0,
       255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,
       255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,
       255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,   0,   0, 255,
       255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,
       255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,
       255, 255, 255, 255, 255,   0,   0, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,
       255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,
       255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,
       255, 255,   0,   0, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,
       255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,
       255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,   0,   0, 255,
       255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,
       255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,
       255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,   0,   0, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,
       255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,
       255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,
       255, 255,   0,   0, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,
       255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,
       255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,   0,   0, 255,
       255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,
       255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,
       255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,   0, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,
       255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,
       255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,
       255, 255, 255, 255,   0,   0,   0,   0, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,
       255, 255, 255, 255])
```

And `diffs` look like this:

```
array([   0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,  255,    0,    0,
          0, -255,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
          0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
          0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
          0,    0,    0,    0,  255,    0, -255,    0,    0,    0,    0,
          0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
          0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
          0,    0,    0,    0,    0,  255,    0, -255,    0,    0,    0,
          0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
          0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
          0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,  255,    0, -255,
          0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
          0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
          0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,  255,    0,
       -255,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
          0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
          0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
        255,    0, -255,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
          0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
          0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
          0,    0,  255,    0, -255,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
          0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
          0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
          0,    0,    0,  255,    0, -255,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
          0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
          0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
          0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,  255, -255,    0,    0,    0,
          0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
          0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
          0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,  255,    0,
          0,    0, -255,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0]
```

And `colStarts` looks like this:

```
[8, 48, 82, 118, 152, 187, 222, 256, 292, 328]
```

And `colEnds` looks like this:

```
[12, 50, 84, 120, 154, 189, 224, 258, 293, 332]
```

Comment: There must be a `np.where()` way of replacing the 2 `for` loops in my code but I couldn't get the syntax right, by the way... something like `colStarts = np.where(diffs>0)` and `colEnds = np.where(diffs<0)`

Comment: can you take a look at what I did in the following link: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/227363/maze-generator-in-python-gif-animator-custom-colors-sizes. It's a different approach because by the time I got your answer I had done it already, anyway check it and suggest how can we tweak the code I did using your approach.